# How do I save several pictureboxes inside a panel?

Tags: c#, image, winforms, bitmap

I do have a panel with several controls and 4 images. The 4 images are inside a frame. Now I would like to save ONLY the 4 pictureboxes (in the frame) into jpg file but the pictureboxes are all white and I see only the panel in the saved image.

```
                Bitmap bmp = new Bitmap(frame.Width, frame.Height);                   
                Rectangle rect = new Rectangle(0, 0, frame.Width, frame.Height);                    

                this.panel1.DrawToBitmap(bmp, rect);                                                            
                bmp.Save("C:\\Temp\\zo.jpg", ImageFormat.Jpeg);
```

How can I do that?

Comment: What did you tried ?

Comment: What you have tried so far? Can you send your sample code?

Comment: Create a bitmap of the necessary size and a Graphics object from it. - then use four DrawImage calls with the right target rectangles and the four pb's Images. Done.

Comment: @TaW could you give an example with "then use four DrawImage"? I think this is exactly the point I am missing here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are (at least) two ways to do it:

- The one your in your code will work fine if the `PictureBoxes` can actually show the images without cutting them off. Note: The `PictureBoxes`  must really sit **inside** the `Panel` (i.e. it must be their `Parent`) or else it will not draw them!

Here is a working example:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   Bitmap bmp = new Bitmap(panel1.ClientSize.Width, panel1.ClientSize.Height);
   using (Graphics G = Graphics.FromImage(bmp))
       panel1.DrawToBitmap(bmp, panel1.ClientRectangle);

   // now we can save it..
   bmp.Save("d:\\foursome.jpg", ImageFormat.Jpeg);
   // and let it go:
   bmp.Dispose();
}
```

- The other way uses `DrawImage` to draw the `Images` in code.

It is more complicated but gives you more control:

```
private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
        Bitmap bmp = new Bitmap(panel1.ClientSize.Width, panel1.ClientSize.Height);

        int x1 = 0;
        int x2 = Math.Max(pictureBox1.Image.Width, pictureBox3.Image.Width);

        int y1 = 0;
        int y2 = Math.Max(pictureBox1.Image.Height, pictureBox2.Image.Height);

        Rectangle rect1 = new Rectangle(new Point(x1, y1), pictureBox1.Image.Size);
        Rectangle rect2 = new Rectangle(new Point(x2, y1), pictureBox2.Image.Size);
        Rectangle rect3 = new Rectangle(new Point(x1, y2), pictureBox3.Image.Size);
        Rectangle rect4 = new Rectangle(new Point(x2, y2), pictureBox4.Image.Size);

        using (Graphics G = Graphics.FromImage(bmp))
        {
            G.DrawImage(pictureBox1.Image, rect1);
            G.DrawImage(pictureBox2.Image, rect2);
            G.DrawImage(pictureBox3.Image, rect3);
            G.DrawImage(pictureBox4.Image, rect4);
        }
        bmp.Save("d:\\foursome2jpg", ImageFormat.Jpeg);
       // and clean up:
       bmp.Dispose();
}
```

This will not only let you add or remove spacing between the Images but also lets you resize them by using [this DrawImage format](https://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/ms142040%28v=vs.110%29.aspx). And of course you could add whatever you want to, eg.g fancy frames or text..

Comment: Thanks for your answer - that works! I do have a rectangle frame added on top of the pictureBox1 but this rectangle is not saved. Is it possible to save it as well?

Comment: I extend the DrawImage with an additional one for the rectangle and it works!