# Cannot add controls to panel in c# Windows Forms

Tags: c#, winforms, controls

I am trying to add several controls like Labels, pictureboxes etc. to a Panel in c# Windows Forms. My code looks like this:

```
this.panel1.Controls.Add(this.label1);
```

Every time I put this in the panel1 section in my Designer.cs, it gets deleted after I switch between classes and forms. I am doing this so that I can "transform" the Panel into a Bitmap with all the other controls in it.

Comment: Why not put it in the, say, *constructor*: `public mainForm() {
      InitializeComponent(); this.panel1.Controls.Add(this.label1);    }`

Comment: _I am doing this so that I can "transform" the Panel into a Bitmap with all the other controls in it._ This is nonsense. You can't do that and instead you should tell us what your ultimate goal is..

Comment: I'd like to save the Panel with the controls in it as a Bitmap, so that it displays e.g. different pictureboxes

Comment: But why? You can a) save it as a Bitmap at runtime using DrawToBitmap or you can write a UserControl. Totally different things. none of which seems to be related with the question you posted, btw.. - . So what is the purpose? Do not repeat yourself but explain with a use case!!

Comment: I am trying to create a risk matrix. It consists of 4 pictureboxes, each one of them with Labels in them that display a number. I thought of putting it in a Panel so that I get a Bitmap from that Panel with the mehtod "savetobitmap"

Comment: Then see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28212031/how-do-i-save-several-pictureboxes-inside-a-panel/28213286?s=33|18.4633#28213286) for an example. - Btw, there may be an issue you will face if the Labels are not really nested in on PictureBoxes.. Are they or are they only placed above them?? Overlapping controls get drawn in reverse order, for some funny reason..

Comment: The issue I mention can be workred around by doing a SendToBack  before and a BringtoFront after the DrawTobitmap for eack Label..

Comment: Have a look `DrawToBitmap()` method, i.e. `panel1.DrawToBitmap(myBitMap, panel1.ClientRectangle);`

Comment: You have read the comment on the top of the designer.cs file where it says you should not edit this file because it will be generated by VS and you will loose your edit ?

Answer (score 1):

Well, as you can see, you are trying to modify code within

```
  #region Windows Form Designer generated code

  ...

  // Designer is supposed to put (or/and remove) any code within this region
  // Do not put any custom code here manually
  this.panel1.Controls.Add(this.label1);

  ...   

  #endregion
```

and you have a *conflict* with Designer. Just let it generate its code in the area which specially designed (and marked out) for that; put yours into, say, constructor:

```
  public MyForm() { 
    // Let .Net initialize the form, create all constrols etc. first
    InitializeComponent(); 

    // Then, run your code here
    this.panel1.Controls.Add(this.label1); 
  }
```

Comment: When I do this, the Panel looks different during runtime and the controls are not at the right place.Do you have any idea why?

Comment: @sfti 2: I think you have to modify at least `Location` property (position of `label1` relativ. top upper corner of the parent client area)

Comment: Why not do it in the designer in the 1st place??

Comment: @TaW: Well, I think there are some reasons (which are not mentioned in the question, alas) for doing it manually. May be there's, say, a condition `if (...) this.panel1.Controls.Add(this.label1);`. I've tried to answer why one should not put code in `Designer` and where it should be written

Comment: Yes, this is true, albeit probalby (?!) not here, since he already was trying to put it in the Desginer,cs ;-) - The pro is of course the wysiwyg you get in the designer, which turns into pita in code..

Answer (score 0):

Try :

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        this.panel1.Controls.Add(this.label1);
    }
}
```